# Adding a foreign key vs. creating a many to many table

Tags: database, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I want someone to tell me what’s the best practice here:

I have a user (the user can be a brand or a normal user), each brand has 1 category (perfume, food, education..) assigned to it. And a user can follow as many brands as they want. I considered a user to have a categoryId if they are a brand, while if they are a normal user then it will be null.

If they are a normal user they will have an entry in the interests table for each category they follow.

My colleague is saying I should remove the CategoryId from the User table, and change the Interests table to be named “UserCategoryRelation” where a brand will have only 1 entry there which is its own category.

I disagreed because of separation of concerns.

Can someone tell me what’s the best practice?

[image]

Comment: Why store brands and users in the same table if they represent different entities?

Comment: I want to use IdentityServer, and it only allows one table for users @GMB